# Using the `stackrel` package with `&` within the `align` environment

Tags: align, ampersand, scalerel

It appears that the `stackrel` package and the `align` environment are incompatible.     The following example illustrates:

```
    \documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{scalerel}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
   \scaleto{f(\alpha,x,y,z)  = & text{some very long expression which I want to shrink }}{32pt}\\
   \scaleto{                 = & text{another very long expression which I want to shrink }}{32pt}
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.6 \end{align*}
```

I want the two = signs to be aligned.    Is there a workaround for this?
I am currently using `scaleto{\phantom{f(\alpha,x,y,z)} =` etc. but it's extremely clumsy and doesn't work very well  Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Also `\mbox{a=&b}` would give errors. What's your aim?

Comment: `align*` needs two columns, and you are using one of them (atm I cannot test in a machine).

Comment: each alignment cell is a group, there are almost no commands that you can use that start in one cell and end in another.  You do not say what you expect this code to do, there are no use cases for a one-row `align`.

Comment: sorry everybody, my mwe was too minimal.    I've expanded my question to be more indicative of what I"m trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have some group spanning the alignment `&` in `align` since `&` itself delineates a group start/end. Instead, you'll have to break the components across `&`, just like you would `\left`...`\right` and other things.

Here's an option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \scaleto{f(\alpha,x,y,z)}{8pt} & \scaleto{{}= \text{some very long expression which I want to shrink}}{8pt} \\
    & \scaleto{{}= \text{another very long expression which I want to shrink}}{8pt}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @Werner, this works sort of, but the problem is that when you break the line into two pieces, and use the same second argument for both pieces you get wildly different amplifications on both sides of the equality sign, as the following line illustrates `\scaleto{f(x)}{32pt} & \scaleto{{}=\left(\frac{\beta}{12}\right)^2}{32pt}`.    The right hand side is shrunk, and the left hand side is expanded.     Is there any way to harmonize both sides except by trial and error?     Thanks!

Comment: @LeoSimon: Of course. This only works if the height of either side matches; then the scaling will be the same. To ensure the height of each component matches the tallest, use `\vphantom{<stuff>}` in the shorter components where `<stuff>` is the tallest component. So, in your example, `\scaleto{f(x)\vphantom{\left(\frac{\beta}{12}\right)^2}}{32pt} & \scaleto{{}=\left(\frac{\beta}{12}\right)^2}{32pt}`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about vphantom.